# (WidgetTest) Test Button State (enabled or disabled)

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, widget-test-flutter

In the initial state, when accessing a view, the button must be disabled and after a specific action, the button must be enabled. Any ideas on how to test this behavior?

Comment: Please post your question in english (https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using `tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(buttonFinder).enabled`

And here is a full example of a test I did before on the same scenario:

```
testWidgets('Button disabled when loading and enabled after result',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {
        LocationBlocMock locationBlocMock = LocationBlocMock();
    
        await tester.pumpWidget(
          MaterialApp(
            home: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return BlocProvider<LocationBloc>(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => locationBlocMock,
                  child: LocationAccess(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
    
        locationBlocMock.add(GetCurrentLocation());
    
        await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    
        final buttonFinder = find.byKey(const Key("give_permission_key"));
    
        expect(buttonFinder, findsOneWidget);
        expect(tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(buttonFinder).enabled, isFalse);
    
        await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    
        expect(tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(buttonFinder).enabled, isTrue);
    
        locationBlocMock.close();
      });
```